# How can I make a button change its background color when pressed down?

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and I wonder if there are any features that can help me. I have the following button CSS:

```
   button {
        background-color: @button-background-color;
        border: 1px solid @button-border;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        color: @button-color;
        background: #e6e6e6;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
        background-image: linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top-color: #ccc;
        border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        display: inline-block;
        line-height: 18px;
        line-height: 1.8rem;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #474747;
        padding: 4px 10px 3px 10px;
        font-family: arial,sans-serif;
        vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

This looks good but I would like to have an effect that appears when I hover over and click on a button without yet releasing the click.

Is there any way that I can catch this with angular and have the class changed for the period when I am holding down the button?

Please note that I am looking for a CSS only or a CSS/AngularJS solution. I am not using jQuery.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

```
button:hover button:active
```

```css
  button {
        background-color: @button-background-color;
        border: 1px solid @button-border;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        color: @button-color;
        background: #e6e6e6;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
        background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top,#fff,#d9d9d9);
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-top-color: #ccc;
        border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,1);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2);
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
    display: inline-block;
        line-height: 18px;
        line-height: 1.8rem;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #474747;
        padding: 4px 10px 3px 10px;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;
        vertical-align: middle;
  }
button:hover 
{
  background: red;
}

button:active 
{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the following css:

```
button:active{
    background-color: red;
}
```

for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp